# Sql Round, when on .5, rounds to the greater number ie 1.235 result 1.24

Tags: sql, sql-server

When doing invoices, i want to round say 1.235 to 1.23

```
Select Round(TestData,2) From TestTableRound
```

why do i get the result 1.24, considering its midway? i want this rounded to 1.23.

This can lead to discrepancies when billing, sometimes the invoice doesnt match the bill.

Just curious, any help would be great, thanks

Comment: It's the default behavior

Comment: DBMS defined. Which one are you using?

Comment: Thanks Minh, but is there anyway around it?

Comment: Using Microsoft SQL Sever Management

Comment: Are you trying to match an existing system that has implemented rounding in that manner? And what is the rule? Is it round ties to an odd digit, to zero, something else? Rounding 5s up is the way I was taught in elementary school (as I imagine most others in Canada and the US were). It wasn't until I started to learn spreadsheets and programming that I learned about rounding bias (and then in engineering at uni, but I started using spreadsheets long before then).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can decrease the amount a litle bit before rounding, like this

```
Select Round(TestData-.001,2) From TestTableRound
```

Another trick (for your case) is to multiply by 100, take the integer part, then divide by 100

```
Select 
 CASE WHEN FLOOR(TestData * 1000)-FLOOR(TestData * 100)*10 <= 5 THEN
          FLOOR(TestData * 100)/100
      ELSE ROUND(TestData , 2)
 END 
 From TestTableRound
```

Comment: Probably a good alternative +1

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia article on rounding should be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding

You may be looking for Banker's Rounding. See this article on Microsoft's implementations: http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/196652

Without more details about what you are trying to achieve, we really can't provide much more help than that.