# Round value only if it is greater than 5

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm not sure that this is a duplicate question.

I need to `ROUND` a value only if the succeeding value is greater than 5.

For example:

If i have **123.4575**, then the rounded value should be **123.457**.

If i have **123.4576**, then the rounded value should be **123.458**.

But the default `ROUND` is not working as i'm expecting. See the below query,

```
select cast(round(123.4575, 3) as decimal(18,3))
```

**Result:**

---

123.458 (where it needs to be 123.457)

I need only three decimal points.

I prefer to suggest me some in-built functions rather than writing functions on my own.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked (many times).  5 is always rounded up by SQL Server.  If you do not want to write your own routine look at Minh's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29541394/sql-round-when-on-5-rounds-to-the-greater-number-ie-1-235-result-1-24?noredirect=1&lq=1).  This shows a neat trick to achieve what you want using a case statement and FLOOR.

Also an easy alternative is to subtract 1 from your number first at a precision 1 greater than your rounding, thus:

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(123.4575 - 0.00001, 3) as decimal(18,3))
```

gives 123.457, whilst

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(123.4576 - 0.00001, 3) as decimal(18,3))
```

gives 123.458